# FileSystemWatcher keeping parent directory

Tags: .net, filesystemwatcher

I am using `FileSystemWatcher` to monitor a folder, and it seems to be preventing the folder's *parent* from being deleted, but doesn't prevent the folder *itself* from being deleted.

For example, I have the file structure:

```
C:\Root\FolderToWatch\...
```

with the `FileSystemWatcher` targeting `FolderToWatch`.  While my program is running, if I go to Windows Explorer and try to delete `Root`, I get an error "Cannot delete Root: access is denied".

However, if I delete `FolderToWatch` FIRST, I can then delete `Root` without incident.

**Here's some code if you want to play with it:**

```
static void Main(string[] args) {

    var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:\Root\FolderToWatch");

    watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
       | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

    watcher.Changed += (sender, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.FullPath);
    watcher.Created += (sender, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.FullPath);
    watcher.Deleted += (sender, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.FullPath);
    watcher.Renamed += (sender, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.FullPath);

    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

    Console.WriteLine("Press \'q\' to quit.");
    while (Console.Read() != 'q');
}
```

**Why does the `FileSystemWatcher` hang onto it's target's parent like that, but not the target itself?**

Answer (score 1):

It is because by deleting the root folder you would also be implicitly deleting any folders it contains, namley in your example "FolderToWatch" which would be owned by the FileSystemWatcher process.

Enjoy!

Comment: But if that's the reason, why is it OK to delete `FolderToWatch` directly?